# What's the difference between microsoft.identity.client and microsoft.identity.web

Tags: azure-active-directory, bearer-token

I'm selecting a package for a WPF desktop client intended to get authentication tokens from AAD. I would like to use the Microsoft Authenticator in the workflow. There seem to be two packages that can do this(see Subject). What is the difference between the two packages and which is most appropriate for a desktop WPF client looking for authentication and a token from AAD? I'm currently using microsoft.identity.client with the microsoft.identity.client.broker (Preview).

Comment: The microsoft.identity.web nuget package description gives you clear guidance that it is used in web apps, it is not for thick or rich clients built using WPF, see https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Web

Comment: You are correct, found it in the readme file.

Comment: can any of u post the solution in the answer section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Nuget package `Microsoft.Identity.Web` is used in Web applications, it is not for thick/rich clients built using WPF or Xamarin, more details are seen in [Nuget gallery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Web)